# PaperJS and drawing an arrow at end of a line when adding multiple tools

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to create some tools on a canvas.  On of the tools I would like to create is a line with an arrow at the end.  I am able to get the code to work on it's own, but when I try and add along side other tools it does not draw the arrowhead, it will only draw a line.  I'm not to sure what I am missing in my code to get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated, maybe there is a better way, I am open to suggestions.

This code does not work;

```
paper.install(window);
var forward;   
window.onload = function() {
  paper.setup('sketx-canvas');
   forward = new Tool();
    var pathforward;
    forward.onMouseDown = function(event) {
        // Create a new path and set its stroke color to black:
        pathforward = new Path({
            segments: [event.point],
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 4,              
        });                            
    }

    // While the user drags the mouse, points are added to the path
    // at the position of the mouse:
    forward.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
        pathforward.add(event.point);
    }     

    // When the mouse is released, we simplify the path and add arrow:
    forward.onMouseUp = function(event) {
        pathforward.simplify(300);     
        var vector  = pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length) - pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length-25); 
        var arrowVector = vector.normalize(18);
        var path2 = new Path({
          segments: [pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length) + arrowVector.rotate(145), pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length), pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length) + arrowVector.rotate(-145)],
          fillColor: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 6,              
        }); 
        path2.scale(1.3);                                     
    }        

}
```

This code does work;

```
    var path;
    function onMouseDown(event) {
        // Create a new path and set its stroke color to black:
        path = new Path({
            segments: [event.point],
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            // if we want dashed lines use dashArray: [2, 4],                
        });                            
    }

    // While the user drags the mouse, points are added to the path
    // at the position of the mouse:
    function onMouseDrag(event) {
        path.add(event.point);
    }     

    // When the mouse is released, we simplify the path and add arrow:
    function onMouseUp(event) {
        path.simplify(300);   ;    
        var vector  = path.getPointAt(path.length) - path.getPointAt(path.length-25); 
        var arrowVector = vector.normalize(18);
        var path2 = new Path({
          segments: [path.getPointAt(path.length) + arrowVector.rotate(145), path.getPointAt(path.length), path.getPointAt(path.length) + arrowVector.rotate(-145)],
          fillColor: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 6,              
        }); 
        path2.scale(1.3);                                     
    }
```

Got it working,  here is the final code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
paper.install(window);
var forward;



window.onload = function() {
  paper.setup('sketx-canvas');
   forward = new Tool();
    var pathforward;
    forward.onMouseDown = function(event) {
        // Create a new path and set its stroke color to black:
        pathforward = new Path({
            segments: [event.point],
            strokeColor: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            // if we want dashed lines use dashArray: [2, 4],                
        });                            
    }

    // While the user drags the mouse, points are added to the path
    // at the position of the mouse:
    forward.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
        pathforward.add(event.point);
    }     

    // When the mouse is released, we simplify the path and add arrow:
    forward.onMouseUp = function(event) {
        pathforward.simplify(300); 
        var point = pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length)
        var vector  = point.subtract(pathforward.getPointAt(pathforward.length-25)); 
        console.log(vector);
        var arrowVector = vector.normalize(18);
        var path2 = new Path({
          segments: [point.add(arrowVector.rotate(145)), point, point.add(arrowVector.rotate(-145))],
          fillColor: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 6,              
        }); 
        path2.scale(1.3);                                     
    }
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle with the code, so we can test it?

Comment: Bad code;http://jsfiddle.net/a0exmfe7/1/

Comment: Good Code;http://jsfiddle.net/pgkrvcdr/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the way you include your script in the script tags. For reasons I don't understand, for certain mathematical operations (such as point additions and subtractions) paper.js needs to have a `<script type="text/paperscript">` tag instead of the regular `text/javascript`.

To show it in your bad code, if you change to `paperscript`, it works.

```
<canvas id="sketx-canvas" width="600" height="319"></canvas>
<br>

<a href="#" onclick="forward.activate();">Forward</a>
<script type="text/paperscript">
    paper.install(window);
    var forward;



    window.onload = function() {

        ...

    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use paperjses .add, .subtract, ... functions for mathematical operations if you want to use `text/javascript` in your script tag instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, I ended up using the add and subtract function and it works perfectly.  I tried text/paperscript and I could not get that to work.